# How do algebraic datatypes relate to free structures?

Tags: inductive-datatypes

I know that:

- Binary leaf trees are free magmas.
- Non-empty lists are free semigroups.
- Lists are free monoids.
- The generalized algebraic datatype `data FM a where {Return::a->FM a; Bind::FM b -> (b->FM a) -> FM a}` is a free monad.

I know also that various abstract datatypes also correspond to free structures—bags are free commutative monoids and finite sets are free commutative idempotent monoids.

Do other algebraic datatypes (e.g., `Maybe`, or 2-3 trees, or binomial trees) also correspond to free algebraic structures? If so, how might those be characterized?

Comment: Via [initial algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_algebra).